# Teradata odbc configuration on Linux

Tags: linux, odbc

I have installed ttu 16.20 on amazon linux and trying to configure it now for application access.

I have the below

and I have set the below path,

When I try to connect to the datasource it throws below error,

Please advice if I am missing something here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ODBC, the data source name is not necessarily the same as the "DBC name" (a.k.a. TDPID) of the Teradata server. Your configuration says that the TDPID is XXXXX and the data source name is TeraDataDev, so when you are asked for the Data Source Name you should enter 'TeraDataDev'.

Comment: That worked,thank you very much.